# JQuery multiple results of radio buttons

Tags: jquery, html, forms, radio-button

quite new to JQuery and Ive run into a problem. I have a form that is made up of 7 or 8 fieldsets, each with a number of radio buttons. What I need to do is remember each selected option of each radio button in each fieldset as well as changing the stored values if the user decides to change their option. The code I have so far is as follows:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
      price = [];
      total = 0;
      function Update_Subtotal(radio){
        $('input:checked').each( function() {
          price[1] = radio.getAttribute('price1');
          price[2] = radio.getAttribute('price2');
        });
        $("#1").text("$" + price[1]);
        $("#2").text("$" + price[2]);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="form" method="post" action="">
      <fieldset style="width: 50%;">
        <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="1" price1="100" class="1" onclick="Update_Subtotal(this);" />Option 1<br />
        <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="2" price1="200" class="1" onclick="Update_Subtotal(this);" />Option 2<br />
        <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="3" price1="300" class="1" onclick="Update_Subtotal(this);" />Option 3<br />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset style="width: 50%;">
        <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="1" price2="10" class="2" onclick="Update_Subtotal(this);" />Option 1<br />
        <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="2" price2="20" class="2" onclick="Update_Subtotal(this);" />Option 2<br />
        <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="3" price2="30" class="2" onclick="Update_Subtotal(this);" />Option 3<br />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    Totals:
    <div id="1"></div>
    <div id="2"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

This works in so far as to show the changed selection in each fieldset, but when moving to the second fieldset, the total of the first shown in

```
<div id="1"></div>
```

becomes

```
$null
```

I cannot change the name, value or classes of the input radio buttons either. Any help was be great, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without re-writing your HTML, you can try this:

```
$(':radio').click(function() {
    $('#1').html($('[name=opt1]:checked').attr('price1'));
    $('#2').html($('[name=opt2]:checked').attr('price2'));
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5LQWs/)**

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! Works almost perfectly. Ive changed the line `function Update_Subtotal(radio){` to `$(document).ready(function(){` so that it shows on first click! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Couple of changes:

1. The main fix is with the `radio.getAttribute('price1')`. Eveytime `Update_Subtotal` is called you are trying to get price1 and price2 from same radio button which is not the case from your HTML. so instead follow the the next two points.
2. You have ids for the divs as 1,2 which are not valid ids. Change them to something like price-1, price-2.
3. You are using custom attributes price1, price2 which are fine, but why not use the HTML5 data-* tags.

Try this:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
    <script>
      var total = 0;
      function Update_Subtotal(radio){
        $('input:checked').each( function(i, el) {
          var price = $(el).data('price');
          $("#price-" + (i + 1)).text("$" + price);
        });
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="form" method="post" action="">
      <fieldset style="width: 50%;">
        <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="1" data-price="100" class="1" onclick="Update_Subtotal(this);" />Option 1<br />
        <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="2" data-price="200" class="1" onclick="Update_Subtotal(this);" />Option 2<br />
        <input type="radio" name="opt1" value="3" data-price="300" class="1" onclick="Update_Subtotal(this);" />Option 3<br />
      </fieldset>
      <fieldset style="width: 50%;">
        <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="1" data-price="10" class="2" onclick="Update_Subtotal(this);" />Option 1<br />
        <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="2" data-price="20" class="2" onclick="Update_Subtotal(this);" />Option 2<br />
        <input type="radio" name="opt2" value="3" data-price="30" class="2" onclick="Update_Subtotal(this);" />Option 3<br />
      </fieldset>
    </form>
    Totals:
    <div id="price-1"></div>
    <div id="price-2"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

http://jsbin.com/obozuk/

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is happening is that when it gets to the second element, it can't find price1 and so puts null.  You can correct this by doing:

```
$('input:checked').each( function() {  
     price[1] = radio.getAttribute('price1') != null ? radio.getAttribute('price1') : price[1];  
     price[2] = radio.getAttribute('price2') != null ? radio.getAttribute('price2') : price[2];  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this too.simple i presume. :)

```
$('input:radio').click(function(){
   $('#1').text($(this).attr('price1'));
   $('#2').text($(this).attr('price2'));
      });​
```

[jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/XH4dh/)